# How to keep standard input stream open?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, stream

I am redirecting all streams (in/out/error) from a commandline application that runs some [ChaiScript](http://chaiscript.com/index.html) scripts. The user is able to interact with a running script via input commands such as `PromptForDouble("Enter a double:");` which are defined in the separate commandline application and not my C# program.

Right now I have a `RichTextBox` that behaves like a console, and is readonly. I have another textbox at the bottom that can be used to "inject" input when needed. However, after the script is tossed into standard input, I'm forced to close standard input, and obviously can't "reopen" it once the script asks the user for input.

My question is how can I "close" standard input after the script is entered, continue with the application (receive output), and enter input again when the user is prompted?

Relevant code:

```
// Executes the script in the specified workspace (workspace only specified for logging)
public ScriptOutput ExecuteScript(WorkArea workspace, string script)
{
    ScriptOutput output;
    output.StdOut = "";
    output.StdErr = "";

    process.Start(); // the instance of the commandline program

    StreamWriter inStream = process.StandardInput;

    inStream.WriteLine(script + "\n//<SCRIPT END>\n");
    inStream.Close();

    output.StdErr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    string line = "";
    while((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        workspace.log(line, false);
    }

    process.WaitForExit();
    //inStream.Close(); <-- closing the stream here makes the program "pause" after the script is entered as it expects more input

    return output;
}
```

`ScriptOutput` is just a lazy way of having stdout and stderr strings in one object (it's a struct). This was coded before tuples so...Sorry :P

tl;dr how do I emulate closing and reopening standard input?

Comment: You will never get null from reading unless the stream was closed by the other end of the connection.  So you will never get out of the while loop while the other program is running.

Comment: @jdweng yeah that's the idea. It runs on a separate thread so I should be able to interact with the opened process anyway, but again, if I don't close stdin, I no longer receive output

Comment: Yeah, but the process terminate if you exit the while loop so there is nothing to connect to.

Comment: @jdweng are you suggesting that if I make the process exit elsewhere that my issue will be resolved?

Comment: I'm suggesting if the process closes you should exit the while loop.  Not 100% sure.  You see if you are at the ReadLine() which blocks I'm not sure windows will always send a null.  When you use ReadLine() with a file when you get to the end of the file windows will send a null and close the file stream.  It is not the same with a pipe (standard input and standard output).  I think removing the WaitForExit() may solve you issue but not sure.